# Access Js Symbol Data

Tags: javascript, node.js

For context I'm poking into and editing a module for my needs.

I have a object called stream which contains a few Symbols which i can get a list of with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(stream)` one of the symbols is `Symbol(connect-options)` i want to access the data this symbol contains, how is this possible?

I have tried:

```js
stream.connect-options
```

FYI i know this doesn't work at all due to the - but i tried anyway

```js
stream["connect-options"]
```

also didn't think this would work but im out of ideas tbh.

Does anyone know how i can access the contents of this symbol, 99% sure the contents are an object as that what it looks like when i log the whole `stream` object.

Any help is appreciated. TIA

Comment: `stream[variable_that_contains_the_symbol]`

Comment: The symbol doesn't contain data, it's used as a key in an object.